# why does the system decides which is bigger by scanning only the first number - Python

Tags: python

this is my code, and when I input numbers that has
two digits and one number that has only one digit,
(e.g. when I input 47, 57, and 9) it results to 9
which is the smallest. please help.

```
def maximum(a, b, c):
        list = [a, b, c]
        return max(list)


num_one = input("Enter 1st Number: ")
num_two = input("Enter 2nd Number: ")
num_three = input("Enter 3rd Number: ")
num4 = 0

if num_one.isdecimal():
    if num_one.isdecimal():
        if num_one.isdecimal():
            a = num_one
            b = num_two
            c = num_three
            print(maximum(a, b, c))
        else:
            print("wrong input")
    else:
        print("wrong input")
else:
    print("wrong input")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Comment: `input()` always returns a string. Comparing strings is done lexicographically, so `"9" > "45"` is indeed true...

Comment: Why are you checking three times the same condition?

Comment: try `print(maximum(int(num_one), int(num_two), int(num_three)))`

Comment: @Ivan it would easier and more readable if they just did `num_x = int(input(...))`...

Comment: @Tomerikoo true! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `input()` it automatically takes in a string. So you have to convert it to a float or integer later. Also, the keyword `and` is useful instead of using three `if` statements:

```
def maximum(a, b, c):
    list = [a, b, c]
    return max(list)

num_one = input("Enter 1st Number: ")
num_two = input("Enter 2nd Number: ")
num_three = input("Enter 3rd Number: ")

if num_one.isdecimal() and num_two.isdecimal() and num_three.isdecimal():
    a = float(num_one)
    b = float(num_two)
    c = float(num_three)
    print(maximum(a, b, c))
else:
    print('Wrong input')
```

Comment: Worth noting that `maximum` is just an unnecessary wrapper to the built-in `max`. i.e. doing `max(a, b, c)` will work exactly the same